# log4cplus:ERROR Re-initializing default context after it has already been destroyed

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I'm running Win32 application (it is unit test based on google test). At the end of the run, when test summary is printed, I've the following failure:

```
log4cplus:ERROR Re-initializing default context after it has already been destroyed.
The memory will be leaked.
```

It seems that log4cplus default context was already destroyed.
Any idea how to prevent it from destroying until all my messages are printed?

Comment: Are you doing any logging after the main function exits? I.e., in dtors of static variables?  Do not.

Comment: Not explicitly. My guess is that Google Test does.

Comment: Try debugging it. Put a breakpoint where the message is being generated, which should be somewhere in [`global-init.cxx`](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/master/src/global-init.cxx#L187).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are logging from dtors of static/global objects which are called after `main()` is exited. This is not supported by log4cplus. It cannot be supported.

Comment: You are right (almost), I was calling shutdown() from dtor.